# android: stack trace for destroy

Tags: android, destroy, activity-finish

My applications main activity is getting "destroyed". I have a Log message in destroy which is getting printed. But the paths where finish is being called is not getting executed.

So i want to know how can i find out what triggered destroy () to be called. Is it finish from my code, or any other system errors.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    try {
        super.onDestroy();

        Log.i("StartUpActivity", "OnDestroy");
        if (asyncTaskForSync != null && !asyncTaskForSync.isCancelled())
            asyncTaskForSync.cancel(true);
        if (DatabaseManager.getInstance() != null)
            DatabaseManager.getInstance().close();

        if (Utils.imageLoader != null)
            Utils.imageLoader.stopThread();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Note: Answer :
I had kept android:noHistory="true" for my startup activity. I wanted this page to be not visible again on back press from other activities. And i had kept all clean up like db close in the destroy of this activity. SO due to nohistory = true, this activity was automatically getting destryed, leading to all resource closing and thus leading to exceptions in my application.

I corrected by removing this flag, and overiding onbackpressed of the second activity.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: ...where have you called finish() in your program ? onDestroy will be called only when you will press the default back button of your mobile or the button where you have written finish or may be in your asyncTask after completion of certain event as it can be seen from your code

Comment: thank you, my issue was different. Thanks for the clues and your time I have edited my que with answer

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why an activity might be destroyed. E.g. if the user rotates the device the default behavior is to destroy the activity and to create a new one.

See "Handling configuration changes" here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and time. I have updated my question with my case and the solution. Thanks again